# UWP App deployment with C# and REST

Tags: c#, rest, uwp

I want to deploy and install an .appxbundle with c# on a UWP(IoT) - Device.

The REST-API documentation is on [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core#app-deployment).

My code is

```
public async static Task<bool> UploadApp(string ip, Stream upload, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (http == null)
                GetHttp();

            HttpContent content = new StreamContent(upload);

            var param = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "package", fileName}

        };

            var urlparam = new FormUrlEncodedContent(param);
            var urlVar = await urlparam.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var response = await http.PostAsync(String.Format("http://{0}:8080/api/app/packagemanager/package?{1}", ip, urlVar), content);

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The code is not working. I get an "Bad request" Error after I send it and I don't know what to change. Could someone help me?

EDIT: The message I get is "Missing .appx (or .eappx) or .appinstaller file in uploaded files". I can deploy and install the package with [ARC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) as "multipart/form-data".

Comment: What happens if you don't Base64-encode the name? You don't need the async call to `ReadAsStringAsync` either. You can just use the static methods on the .NET `Uri` class to encode the query-string parameters.

Comment: You are right the Base64 encode is false. I change it. But it doesn't work, yet. The response message says "Missing .appx (or .eappx) or .appinstaller file in uploaded files".

Comment: As the error info, it seems that you don't pass the package file in your post request. Could you provide more info about your final post request?

Comment: I am using the plugin "Restsharper" now. I don't know why it is not working with a standard http Request. If wished I can post the restsharper code here.

Comment: Please make sure your Stream is correct and could be identify to be a .appx file to be installed on the device. It would be better if you can provide a simple sample to help me see the issue.